# HTML Carousel, how to recover images from it?

Tags: php, jquery, html, dom, carousel

I have a carousel from newspaper that i need to parse. it looks like the next photo:

[image]

I have to recover all the photos from it, how must i do? I already save this "div" in a PHP variable, but when i get the file image, i only get one, not all of them. Why?

This is my PHP code:

```
$data31 = $this->html->find('#vplfgp_embeb', 0);
$data32 = $data31->find('.gallery-buttons', 0);
```